# Join in LINQ within a where clause

Tags: c#, linq

I have a database structure which has a set of users and their UserId

I then have a table called 'Post' which consists of a text field and a CreatedBy field.

I then have a 'Follows' table which consists of 'WhoIsFollowing' and 'WhoTheyFollow' fields.

The idea is that the 'Follows' table maps which users another user 'Follows'.

If I am using the application as a particular user and I want to get all my relevant 'Posts', these would be posts of those users I follow, or my own posts.

I have been trying to get this into one LINQ statement but have been failing to get it perfect. Ultimately I need to query the 'Posts' table for all the 'Posts' that I have posted, joined with all the posts of the people I follow in the 'Follows' table.

I have got it working with this statement

```
 postsWeWant = (from s in db.Posts
                join sa in db.Follows on s.CreatedBy equals sa.WhoTheyAreFollowing into joinTable1
                from x in joinTable1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                where (x.WhoIsFollowing == userId || s.CreatedBy == userId) && !s.Deleted
                orderby s.DateCreated descending
                select s).Take(25).ToList();
```

The issue is that it seems to come back with duplicates for all the posts posted by the user themselves. I have added .Distinct() to get around this, but instead of taking 25 posts each time, the duplicates are meaning it comes back with much less when there are a lot of posts by that user in the latest 25.

First off, why is the above coming back with duplicates? (It would help me understand the statement a bit more), and secondly how do I get around it?

Comment: why you doing left outer join?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad i think he's trying to include posters that are not following anyone

Answer (score 2):

Its difficult to say exactly without the data structure, but I would recommend investigating and perhaps expanding your join to eliminate duplicate association.

If that fails then I would use a group by clause to remove duplicates so there is no need for a distinct. The reason you are ending up with less than 25 records is probably because the elimination of duplicates is happening after taking 25. But I think I would need more of your code to tell for sure.